# Undefined method 'gsup' for "text":string (nomethoderror)

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie with Ruby programming and don't really know much about it. I'm having this problem with an exercise where is a string from which I try to delete some marks ("!") and to replace some letters to another ("la" -> "ca"). Something like this:

```
text = "Lava lamp!!"
text = text.chomp.delete("!")
text = text.gsup("la","ca")
puts text
```

And it only gives me this error: "program.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method`gsup' for "lava lamp":string (nomethoderror)"

Can you please help me?

Comment: I do, the dot was just my mistake. I've remake it and it still gives the same error.

Comment: The `.` was one problem. You misspelled the method name: It's `gsub` not `gsup`.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [`gsub`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) not `gsup`

`text = text.gsub("la","ca")`

Comment: The dot was an accident, I've put it -> text.gsup("la","ca")

Answer (score 1):

user2169701, you need to use gsu**b** in place of gsu**p**

```
text = text.gsub("la","ca")
```